# Finding items in a list and then displaying back those values

Tags: postgresql

Suppose I have a list of email addresses,

```
'a@a.com', 'b@b.com', 'c@c.com'
```

I would like to find these email addresses in the table and then display them back in the results, and then also display the values that were NOT in the table.

My current query is as follows,

```
SELECT email, first_name, last_name
FROM user_table
WHERE email IN ('a@a.com', 'b@b.com'....)
```

How would I get it to display the values that are also NOT in the table from the same list? I've tried using CTEs and such and haven't had much luck. TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to list user for an email from a string of addresses you are first going to split those into individual entries. Then since you also want to know which in your list are not in the table you LEFT join the table to the resulting individual entries: (see [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=9d9a41194c137c9bea2e9ac2b2eb07e6)).

```
with email_list (email) as 
     ( select unnest(string_to_array('&list_of_emails', ',')) )     
select el.email
     , coalesce(ut.first_name,'Not in User_Table') first_name
     , ut.last_name
  from email_list      el
  left join user_table ut 
    on ut.email = el.email;
```

The real work is done in the emails_list CTE. The function string_to_array breaks the comma delimited strings apart and creates an array of strings. The unnest function then split that array into individual rows. After that the main query is a simple left join operation.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, I never heard of that fiddle thing and I am checking it out. Pretty cool.

Comment: It is! Not only does it work for demonstrating answers it is also a pretty good forum for setting up question and sampling data for them.